# Create a Combined CSV Files

Tags: pandas, neural-network, dataset

I have two CSV files `reviews_positive.csv` and `reviews_negative.csv`. How can I combine them into one CSV file, but in the following condition:

- Have odd rows fill with reviews from `reviews_positive.csv` and even rows fill up with reviews from `reviews_negative.csv`.
- I am using Pandas

I need this specific order because I want to build a balanced dataset for training using neural networks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example

```
from io Import StringIO
import pandas as pd

pos = """rev
a
b
c"""

neg = """rev
e
f
g
h
i"""

pos_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(pos))
neg_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(neg))
```

***Solution***
*`pd.concat` with the `keys` parameter to label the source dataframes as well as to preserve the desired order of positive first.  Then we `sort_index` with parameter `sort_remaining=False`*

```
pd.concat(
    [pos_df, neg_df],
    keys=['pos', 'neg']
).sort_index(level=1, sort_remaining=False)

      rev
pos 0   a
neg 0   e
pos 1   b
neg 1   f
pos 2   c
neg 2   g
    3   h
    4   i
```

---

That said, you don't have to interweave them to take balanced samples.  You can use `groupby` with `sample`

```
pd.concat(
    [pos_df, neg_df],
    keys=['pos', 'neg']
).groupby(level=0).apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, n=3)

          rev
pos pos 1   b
        2   c
        0   a
neg neg 1   f
        4   i
        3   h
```

Comment: This solution worked right out of the box and the explanations are well on point. You are a data genius @piRSquared